# Python script that polls for changes in filesystems

Tags: python, file-system

This is a (relatively) cleaned-up version of a Python script I've been working on for the past day or two based on [Tim Golden's first solution](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html) to the above problem. I know about watchdog but I'm trying to keep dependencies down to a minimum.

I'm concerned about how Pythonic my code is, as this is the first "real" script I've worked on. I'm also unsure of whether I have any redundancies (like all the `if not ignored else None`s) or inefficiencies in my code.

Any comments on how I can properly refactor the script are appreciated.

**ianus.py**

```
import os

def ianus(path, interval=60, recursive=True, ignore_dirs=False, ignore_files=False):
    import time

    def path_join(root, dest):
        return os.path.join(root, dest)

    def path_replace(path):
        return path.replace('\\', '/') + ['', '/'][os.path.isdir(path)]

    def pathify(root, dest):
        return path_replace(path_join(root, dest))

    def mod_time(root, dest):
        return os.stat(pathify(root, dest)).st_mtime

    def build(path, recursive=True, ignore_dirs=False, ignore_files=False):
        def flatten(list):
            return [item for sublist in list for item in sublist]

        if recursive:
            walk = list(os.walk(path)) if recursive else None

            rdirs  = flatten(
                    [[pathify(root, dir) for dir in dirs] for (root, dirs) in \
                    [(root, dirs) for (root, dirs, files) in walk]])          \
                    if not ignore_dirs else None

            rfiles = flatten(
                    [[pathify(root, f) for f in files] for (root, files) in   \
                    [(root, files) for (root, dirs, files) in walk]])         \
                    if not ignore_files else None
        else:
            l = [pathify(path, u) for u in os.listdir(path)]

            rdirs  = [d for d in l if os.path.isdir(d)]  \
                    if not ignore_dirs else None

            rfiles = [f for f in l if os.path.isfile(f)] \
                    if not ignore_files else None

        return rdirs, rfiles

    path = path_replace(path)

    print 'Watching ' + path + '...'
    print '---'

    dirs_before, files_before = build(path, recursive, ignore_files, ignore_dirs)

    dir_times  = [(d, mod_time(path, d)) for d in dirs_before]  \
                 if not ignore_dirs else None   
    file_times = [(f, mod_time(path, f)) for f in files_before] \
                 if not ignore_files else None

    while True:
        time.sleep(interval)

        dirs_after, files_after = build(path, recursive, ignore_dirs, ignore_files)

        new_dir_times  = [(d, mod_time(path, d)) for d in dirs_after]  \
                         if not ignore_dirs else None
        new_file_times = [(f, mod_time(path, f)) for f in files_after] \
                         if not ignore_files else None

        msg = [None, None]

        if not ignore_dirs:
            dirs_added   = [d for d in dirs_after if not d in dirs_before]
            dirs_removed = [d for d in dirs_before if not d in dirs_after]
            dirs_updated = [d[0] for d in new_dir_times if not        \
                           ((d in dir_times) or (d[0] in files_added))]
            msg[0] = (dirs_added, dirs_removed, dirs_updated)

        if not ignore_files:
            files_added   = [f for f in files_after if not f in files_before]
            files_removed = [f for f in files_before if not f in files_after]
            files_updated = [f[0] for f in new_file_times if not        \
                            ((f in file_times) or (f[0] in files_added))]
            msg[1] = (files_added, files_removed, files_updated)

                    print msg
        print '---'

        dirs_before  = dirs_after
        files_before = files_after

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('-p', type=str,
                        help='Set the path to be watched.')
    parser.add_argument('-intr', type=int,
                        help='Set the poll interval of the watching thread.')
    parser.add_argument('-rec',
                        help='Checks all subdirectories for changes.')
    parser.add_argument('--ignd',
                        help='Ignores directories. Leaves msg[0] as None.',
                        action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--ignf',
                        help='Ignores files. Leaves msg[1] as None.',
                        action='store_true')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    path = os.getcwd()
    interval = 60
    recursive, ignore_dirs, ignore_files = False, False, False

    if args.p:
        if os.path.isdir(args.p):
            path = args.p
        else:
            print 'Not a valid directory.'
            sys.exit(1)
    if args.intr:
        if args.intr < 10:
            print 'Too short an interval.'
            sys.exit(1)
        else:
            interval = args.intr
    if args.rec:
        recursive = True
    if args.ignd:
        ignore_dirs = True  
    if args.ignf:
        ignore_files = True

    if(ignore_dirs and ignore_files):
        print 'Both directories and files are ignored. Nothing is watched.'
        sys.exit(1)

    ianus(path, interval, recursive, ignore_dirs, ignore_files)
```

Comment: Readers may be interested in an alternative solutions to this problem, such as this one, and the others on the same page: http://superuser.com/a/970780/57697

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There are no docstrings. What do your functions do, what arguments do they take, and what do they return?
2. It's not clear to me what I could use your program for. The output is produced like this:

   ```
   print msg
   print '---'
   ```

   where `msg` is a complicated Python data structure (a list of tuples of lists of strings). There's no easy way for me to use this output in a shell script: it would take too much parsing.

   So what are the use cases for your program?
3. Your code does not run under Python 3.
4. You've defined a bunch of functions inside the function `ianus`. Presumably this is for reasons of "privacy" — the functions are only called in this context, so you have defined them there. However, in Python we generally don't define local functions like this unless we have a better reason than "privacy" (such as use of variables from the local scope). It would be simpler to define these functions at top level.
5. `path_join` is just a wrapper around [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) and so seems hardly worth defining. But if you really insisted on having such an alias, you could create it like this:

   ```
   path_join = os.path.join
   ```

   or like this:

   ```
   from os.path import join as path_join
   ```
6. You call `pathify` all over the place but I doubt this is necessary. The paths mostly come from [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) and so should be fine without this kind of manipulation.
7. A function that does the same thing as your `flatten` is already in the standard library: [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).
8. You always test `not ignore_files` and `not ignore_dirs`. This suggests that these Booleans are the wrong way round and you should have named them `watch_files` and `watch_dirs` instead.
9. You set `rfiles` to `None` if `ignore_files` is set. This means you have to keep testing `if not ignore_files`. But if you had set `rfiles` to the empty list in that case, then you could skip the test in several places (because iterating over the empty list would yield no files).
10. You don't need to use backslashes to continue lines inside brackets. So the backslash here is unnecessary:

    ```
    dirs_updated = [d[0] for d in new_dir_times if not        \
                   ((d in dir_times) or (d[0] in files_added))]
    ```
11. The parentheses here are unnecessary:

    ```
    if(ignore_dirs and ignore_files):
    ```

    (Python is not C.)
12. After collecting files and directories into separate lists `dirs_after` and `files_after`, you treat them almost identically. The only difference is that changes to directories go into `msg[0]` and changes to files go into `msg[1]`. Is this distinction really necessary? If not, why not just keep one list containing all watched paths, and simplify the code accordingly.
13. This code seems over-complicated, with double list comprehensions:

    ```
    if recursive:
        walk = list(os.walk(path)) if recursive else None

        rdirs  = flatten(
                [[pathify(root, dir) for dir in dirs] for (root, dirs) in \
                [(root, dirs) for (root, dirs, files) in walk]])          \
                if not ignore_dirs else None

        rfiles = flatten(
                [[pathify(root, f) for f in files] for (root, files) in   \
                [(root, files) for (root, dirs, files) in walk]])         \
                if not ignore_files else None
    else:
        l = [pathify(path, u) for u in os.listdir(path)]

        rdirs  = [d for d in l if os.path.isdir(d)]  \
                if not ignore_dirs else None

        rfiles = [f for f in l if os.path.isfile(f)] \
                if not ignore_files else None
    ```

    I would write it like this:

    ```
    watched_paths = []
    if recursive:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            if watch_dirs:
                watched_paths.extend(os.path.join(root, d) for d in dirs)
            if watch_files:
                watched_paths.extend(os.path.join(root, f) for f in files)
    else:
        for entry in os.listdir(path):
            entry = os.path.join(path, entry)
            if (watch_dirs and os.path.isdir(entry)
                or watch_files and os.path.isfile(entry)):
                watched_paths.append(entry)
    ```
14. You've spelled the arguments `-intr` and `-rec` with a single hyphen. Generally you should reserve single hyphens for options with just one letter. So I would change these to `-i` and `-r` respectively (with long versions `--interval` and `--recursive`).
15. In your argument parsing code, you should use the [`default`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#default) keyword to [`ArgumentParser.add_argument`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument) to simplify the argument processing. For example, instead of:

    ```
    parser.add_argument('-rec',
                        help='Checks all subdirectories for changes.')
    parser.add_argument('--ignd',
                        help='Ignores directories. Leaves msg[0] as None.',
                        action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--ignf',
                        help='Ignores files. Leaves msg[1] as None.',
                        action='store_true')

    # ...

    recursive, ignore_dirs, ignore_files = False, False, False 

    # ...

    if args.rec:
        recursive = True
    if args.ignd:
        ignore_dirs = True  
    if args.ignf:
        ignore_files = True
    ```

    `
    you could write:

    ```
    parser.add_argument('-rec', default=False,
                        help='Checks all subdirectories for changes.',
                        action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--ignd', default=False,
                        help='Ignores directories. Leaves msg[0] as None.',
                        action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--ignf', default=False,
                        help='Ignores files. Leaves msg[1] as None.',
                        action='store_true')
    ```

    though as explained above I would recommend reversing the sense of the option variables and write something like this instead:

    ```
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--recursive', default=False,
                        help='Checks all subdirectories for changes.',
                        action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--ignore-dirs', dest='watch_dirs', default=True,
                        help='Ignore directories?',
                        action='store_false')
    parser.add_argument('--ignore-files', dest='watch_files', default=True,
                        help='Ignore files?',
                        action='store_false')
    ```

Comment: Thank you! That was very comprehensive and helpful. If you wouldn't mind, I still have a few questions to address to you.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's generally good! There are a few little things that stand out to me as being repetitive and not quite Pythonic.

For instance the block at the end could be rewritten to avoid all the extra assignments. Unless you think they add readability. In which case I would suggest that the argument names themselves should be changed.

```
if(args.ignd and args.ignf):
    print 'Both directories and files are ignored. Nothing is watched.'
    sys.exit(1)

ianus(args.p, args.intr, args.rec, args.ignd, args.ignf)
```

By default, if an optional argument isn't given to argparse it is given the value of None. Which in Python is falsy. So in the block below you don't need the third line at all.

```
path = os.getcwd()
interval = 60
recursive, ignore_dirs, ignore_files = False, False, False
```

The other two lines could be made default arguments.

```
parser.add_argument('-p', type=str, default=os.getcwd(),
                    help='Set the path to be watched.')
parser.add_argument('-intr', type=int, default=60,
                    help='Set the poll interval of the watching thread.')
```

It's generally accepted in Python that imports go at the top of the module/script unless you have a really good reason for delaying the import. I can't see one in this case.

You have a helper function called `path_join`. Which is fine. But it could just as easily have been written like so

```
path_join = os.path.join
```

No need to create a new function that calls an existing one with exactly the same signature. If you want to call it something else for readability just assign it to a variable.

One thing that most Python people attempt to do is write in a highly readable style. Generally avoiding shorter variable names and instead attempting to use full nouns. For instance I might write this block

```
l = [pathify(path, u) for u in os.listdir(path)]
```

As

```
contents = [pathify(path, child) for child in os.listdir(path)]
```

For the same reason most people agree that double negatives are harder to read/grok. So I might change my variable names and set the defaults to True rather than False, like below:

```
rfiles = [f for f in l if os.path.isfile(f)] \
    if watch_files else None
```

Comment: Thanks! Concerning imports, I thought that you import what you need in a function so that when you need to import *that* function in another script, that library gets imported as well. Is that not the case?

Comment: That is not the case. In Python there is no way to import a function from a module without loading the module itself. For the interpreter to even be aware of a function definition in a module it has to load it.